# Fixing ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception, pixel

What Im trying to do here is to use an if statement to test if the pixels y position is greater or equal to the size of the y axis. If it is. Break out of the for loop, however I still get the ArrayOutOfBoundsException. How should I use the break function when working with loops?

```
public void render() {
    counter++;
    if (counter % 100 == 0) {
        time++;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        if (y >= HEIGHT - 10) break;
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {

            pixels[time + time * WIDTH] = 0xff00ff;
        }

        if (y >= HEIGHT - 1) break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace of your exception

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-2"             java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48762
 at com.game.graphics.Screen.render(Screen.java:38)
 at com.game.Game.render(Game.java:101)
 at com.game.Game.run(Game.java:81)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please post the *complete* stacktrace of your exception nicely formatted to your question. Which line is line 38 of your file Screen.java?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the value calculated by `time + time * WIDTH` is bigger or equal the ammount of elements in `pixels`

Answer (score 0):

```
pixels[time + time * WIDTH] = 0xff00ff;
```

If I understand your code, you do not change the time in the loop, so probably you should multiply time + time by x or y (not the WIDTH) because WIDTH is const.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Johannes answer, you are calculating the index into the pixel array incorrectly. Your calculation of `time + time * WIDTH` will likely not yield your desired results, as the value of `time` is initialized outside the `render()` method, but it is incremented every time the `render()` method is called. Assuming `time` is set to 0 initially, then you will get an AOOB exception after you have called `render()` `HEIGHT` times.

What you probably meant to write was

```
for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        pixels[x + y * WIDTH] = 0xff00ff;
    }
}
```

Presuming your pixels array is at least `WIDTH`x `HEIGHT` in size then this will not have an AOOB exception.